# Inserting A New Tile In The Next Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a behaviour similar to Google Image where clicking on one of the tiles in a grid would insert an element at the end of the row. I have a solution, but was wondering if there is a more efficient algorithm?

I have a grid of tiles, all with various column widths that are floated left. I am comparing the Y coordinate of the tile clicked with the next sets of tiles' Y coordinates. If their Y coordinates do not match the original Y coordinate, I know that tile belongs to the next row.

Is there a more efficient algorithm?

```
$('.tile').click( function() {
    var ele = $(this),
        eleY = ele.position().top,
        next = ele,
        nextY = eleY;

    while (eleY == nextY) {
        next = $(next).next()[0];
        nextY = $(next).position().top;
    }

    $(next).before('<div class="tile col-6">My New Tile</div>'); 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9ku6shr/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't prove that this is more efficient but this is the approach I did.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9ku6shr/7/)

```
$('.tile').click( function() {

    showNew(this);

});

function showNew(tile)
{
    var newtile = '<div class="tile tile--new col-6">My New Tile</div>';
    if( $(tile).next('div').length )
    {
      var nextdiv = $(tile).next('div');
      if(nextdiv.position().top > $(tile).position().top)
      {
        $(tile).after(newtile);
      }
      else
      {
        showNew( nextdiv );
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $(tile).after(newtile);
    } 
}
```